How to back-transform inverse transformation in emmeans when using contrast function
I am trying to calculate pairwise comparisons using the {emmeans} package after fitting a linear model with an inverse-transformed response. Here is the data and fitted model. The data comes from the {faraway} package.
> data("rats", package = "faraway")
> m <- lm(1/time ~ treat + poison, data = rats)

After fitting the model I can get estimated marginal means that are back-transformed using the following code:
> emmeans(m3, specs = "treat", type = "response", tran = "inverse") 
 treat response     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A        0.284 0.0115 42    0.263    0.309
 B        0.537 0.0411 42    0.465    0.635
 C        0.339 0.0164 42    0.309    0.376
 D        0.463 0.0305 42    0.408    0.534

Results are averaged over the levels of: poison 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the inverse scale 

However, when I then try to calculate pairwise comparisons using the contrast() function, the results are not back-transformed.
> emmeans(m3, specs = "treat", type = "response", tran = "inverse") |> 
+   contrast("pairwise")
 contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 A - B       1.657 0.201 42   8.233  <.0001
 A - C       0.572 0.201 42   2.842  0.0335
 A - D       1.358 0.201 42   6.747  <.0001
 B - C      -1.085 0.201 42  -5.391  <.0001
 B - D      -0.299 0.201 42  -1.485  0.4551
 C - D       0.786 0.201 42   3.905  0.0018

Results are averaged over the levels of: poison 
Note: contrasts are still on the inverse scale 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 

I have tried moving the type = "response", tran = "inverse" arguments to the contrast() function but that produces unusual results:
> emmeans(m3, specs = "treat") |> 
+   contrast("pairwise", type = "response", tran = "inverse")
 contrast response  SE df null t.ratio p.value
 A - B           1   0 42  Inf   8.233  <.0001
 A - C           2   1 42  Inf   2.842  0.0335
 A - D           1   0 42  Inf   6.747  <.0001
 B - C         Inf Inf 42  Inf  -5.391  <.0001
 B - D         Inf Inf 42  Inf  -1.485  0.4551
 C - D           1   0 42  Inf   3.905  0.0018

I have also tried the following but still get the same result (comparisons still on inverse scale).
tran <- make.tran("inverse")
m2 <- with(tran, lm(linkfun(time) ~ treat + poison, data = rats))
emmeans(m2, specs = "treat", type = "response") |> 
  contrast("pairwise")

My question: Is there a way to get contrasts that are back-transformed from the inverse scale?

You have to be careful.  If you inverse transform your data you can transform predictions back to the original scale, but back-transforming differences (contrasts) back is sometimes tricky and sometimes impossible. (For example,  if you work on a log-odds scale you can back-transform predictions to the probability scale, but can only back-transform contrasts to an odds scale ...) It's possible that the marginaleffects package would help you get the equivalent of "contrasts on the data scale"

This is well-documented and is a matter of deciding what you want to be talking about. If you do
emm <- emmeans(..., type = "response")

then the means in emm are still on the transformed scale, but back-transformed to the response scale. When we do
contrast(emm, ...)

the contrasts are still computed on the transformed scale. If type = "response" is in force, then those results are back-transformed, but only if there is a valid way to do that. For example, if the transformation is the log, then a comparison of two means is of the form log(a) - log(b) which is equal to log(a/b), hence back-transforming it will yield an estimate of a/b.
However, with the inverse scale, because there is no way to back-transform 1/a - 1/b, so the results are reported on the inverse scale, with a message.
If really what you wanted was an estimate of mean(1/a) - mean(1/b), that can be done but we don't do mind-reading, you have to ask for it. That is accomplished via the regrid() function, which re-casts all the estimates to a new scale:
remm <- regrid(emm)    # back-transforms to the response scale by default
contrast(remm, ...)

By the same token, if you really wanted to estimate the ratios of the response means, you could do
contrast(regrid(emm, transform = "log"), ...)

See the help page for regrid() for more information. You can also find a detailed discussion of how transformations are dealt with in the "transformations" vignette.

Sorry, I don’t know how to do this in emmeans. Hopefully someone will come in with an answer. But as @ben-bolker suggested in comments, you can do this relatively easily with marginaleffects, though it requires some care with the order of operations.
First, we estimate the model and run the emmeans command for reference:
library(emmeans)
library(marginaleffects)
data("rats", package = "faraway")
m <- lm(1 / time ~ treat + poison, data = rats)

emmeans(m, specs = "treat", type = "response", tran = "inverse")
>  treat response     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
>  A        0.284 0.0115 42    0.263    0.309
>  B        0.537 0.0411 42    0.465    0.635
>  C        0.339 0.0164 42    0.309    0.376
>  D        0.463 0.0305 42    0.408    0.534
> 
> Results are averaged over the levels of: poison 
> Confidence level used: 0.95 
> Intervals are back-transformed from the inverse scale

Now, we use the marginaleffects::avg_prediction() function to replicate the results. The arguments say:

newdata: Make predictions on a “balanced” grid of predictors, that is, for each combination of categorical factors and numeric variables held at their means.
by: Compute aggregate predictions by treat subgroups.
byfun: Use a custom aggregation function to take the inverse of the mean of predictions.

This is equivalent to what emmeans does under the hood
p <- avg_predictions(m,
  newdata = datagrid(grid_type = "balanced"),
  by = "treat",
  byfun = \(x) mean(x)^-1)
p
> 
>  treat Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)     S 2.5 % 97.5 %
>      A    0.284     0.0115 24.7   <0.001 445.8 0.262  0.307
>      B    0.537     0.0411 13.1   <0.001 127.4 0.457  0.618
>      C    0.339     0.0164 20.7   <0.001 313.9 0.307  0.371
>      D    0.463     0.0305 15.2   <0.001 170.5 0.403  0.522
> 
> Columns: treat, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
> Type:  response

Finally, we add the hypothesis="pairwise" function to the above call to get the quantities you want:
avg_predictions(m,
  newdata = datagrid(grid_type = "balanced"),
  by = "treat",
  byfun = \(x) mean(x)^-1,
  hypothesis = "pairwise")
> 
>   Term Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)    S   2.5 %  97.5 %
>  A - B  -0.2529     0.0426 -5.93  < 0.001 28.3 -0.3365 -0.1694
>  A - C  -0.0552     0.0200 -2.76  0.00586  7.4 -0.0944 -0.0159
>  A - D  -0.1786     0.0326 -5.48  < 0.001 24.5 -0.2425 -0.1148
>  B - C   0.1978     0.0442  4.47  < 0.001 17.0  0.1111  0.2844
>  B - D   0.0743     0.0511  1.45  0.14612  2.8 -0.0259  0.1746
>  C - D  -0.1234     0.0346 -3.57  < 0.001 11.4 -0.1913 -0.0556
> 
> Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
> Type:  response

Note that the comparions, as expected, equivalent to manual computation using the previous command:
p$estimate[1] - p$estimate[2]
> [1] -0.2529296

